# Debian Shell program not working properly

Tags: bash, cron, debian, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I wrote a simple script to ceck if the deluge demon is running and if not to restart it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(pidof deluged | wc -1) -eq 0 ]]; then
    deluged
fi
```

I added it to scheduled job on cron to make it run every 5 minutes...everything work fine, if I kill the deluge demon (deluged) my script restart it correctly.

My problem is that one:

I'm using deluge to download torrents, but sometimes it lost the connection with the localhost (127.0.0.1) and periodically I have to check if it still running, how can I improve the above code to automatically reconnect to the host?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you run another job that will kill it every 15 minutes?

Comment: @ergonaut what do you mean? I need to only reconnect to the host automatically if it is disconnected..

Comment: I'm suggesting you kill the process, because your original job will restart it anyways, and you will establish your lost connection.

Comment: @ergonaut Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind as a possible solution, but I prefer to check if it is disconnect and then, if so, recconect it..